# Difference between windows and unix paths

Tags: php, windows, unix, path

My test server is windows.
Live server is unix.

I was using relative paths, which seemed to work identically on both.
I changed to absolute paths and it seems the two are different.

My problem stems from files being loaded from subdirectories. 
On the windows server I am using `realpath()`, and this seems to give me a 'root' to locate from. But unix treats this different?

What is the usual method of matching unix absolute paths to windows?

**Problem Found :** The cause was `require()`.

It seems windows permits a 'superfluous' '/' prefixed, so

`require '/ajax/test.php'` is valid on windows but not on unix.

Comment: First things first: Windows uses drive letters. *-grunt grumble-*

Comment: First things first:  your test server should have an environment identical to your live server.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis How is that an answer to this person's question, or a solution to their problem?

Comment: @toon81: You know you're replying to a comment, right...?

Comment: @mahks you should post the solution you found as an answer

Comment: @BoltClock Why yes, I do. In fact, I agree with the comment. But the question is clear enough, first of all, and that comment is like saying: "It hurts when you touch that? Well then leave it alone!" Second, this person may not be the server admin for either server. Third, maybe they're learning as a beginner and tinkering at home. In that case, does mr McNellis seriously think advising someone to install Linux is a good idea? I'd recommend against trying to set up a Linux box unless you're comfortable with the system. It's one thing to run Firefox, but quite another to set up a LAMP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Found : The cause was require().

It seems windows permits a superfluous '/' prefixed, so

require '/ajax/test.php'` is accepted on windows but unix returns an error.

Comment: It's valid on Unix... it just doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that, considering you are working on different environments for live and dev, you restrict upload folders and that you create a static map between your Windows and Linux environments.

Also, just in case you haven't seen this, the documentation on PHP.net about realpath describes the differences between Linux and Windows quite clearly:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: +1 I didn't know `realpath()` dealt with Unix-like paths smartly on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have defined/static variables in config file which is loaded everywhere. It's easy very reliable approach IMHO.