# What are all the differences between Unix and Windows paths?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, path

As the question suggests I would like to know what all the differences in the way unix systems and windows systems see and format paths. I write a lot of code that needs to run on both platforms and problems with paths crop up often. Just out of interest I am also planning on writing my own converter.

I realize this question: [Difference between windows and unix paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627416/difference-between-windows-and-unix-paths) exists but its been solved and the focus was solving the dudes actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wiki link will help you figure out the differences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

In short the Paths on both Unix and Windows are used for locating executables with two notable difference among these two:

1. Superuser on Unix systems don't add current directory as a rule, this is as mentioned to stop accidental execution of commands from current directory.
2. On Windows some graphical programs don't show up on command line as they are supposed to be run from a GUI.